# Erro ao enviar Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Tenho o seguinte variável:**

json_envio = JSON.stringify(obj);

**o valor da mesma é:**

```
 "{"usuario":
     {"login":"gleyson",
      "senha":"1"},
 "razao_social":"INTELIDER",
 "nome_fantasia":"INTELIDER LTDA",
 "cpf_cnpj":"10999558000186",
 "rg_insc_estadual":"11111",
 "tipo":"F"}"
```

**Estou usando Jquery Ajax para enviar, porém, esta caindo na exceção do código abaixo**:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/api/pessoas",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      data: json_envio,
      success: function (result) {
          alert('tudo certo');
      },
      error: function (exception) { alert('Exeption:' + JSON.stringify(exception)); }
```

**O erro é o seguinte:**

```
Exeption:{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"
A solicitação é inválida.\",\"ModelState\":{\"pessoa.tipo\":[\"O campo tipo 
é obrigatório.\"],\"pessoa.razao_social\":[\"O campo razao_social é 
obrigatório.\"]}}","responseJSON":{"Message":"A solicitação é 
inválida.","ModelState":{"pessoa.tipo":["O campo tipo é 
obrigatório."],"pessoa.razao_social":["O campo razao_social é 
obrigatório."]}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

Pelo erro entendi que ele está reclamando do campo tipo e razao_social, porém, ambos estão no Json que está na variável json_envio e pegando o valor do mesmo e utilizando o soapUI, consigo enviar sem problema. O que pode estar errado?

imagem do valor do obj:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que converte json objeto para string se o dataType é json? Me parece não precisar de `JSON.stringify(obj);`

Comment: @LucasCosta O `dataType` define o tipo de dado esperado na resposta do servidor, não do dado enviado ao mesmo.

Comment: A questão é: qual o código em `/api/pessoas`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é um serviço em WebApi, porém se consigo enviar pelo souap não deveria conseguir envia pelo ajax também? Quer que eu coloque o código da entidade e o controller?

Comment: Sim. Você chegou a verificar quais são os dados que chegam na API desta forma?

Comment: @InteliderSistemas podes enviar somente `obj` no `data:`. O jQuery já converte isso, por isso não precisas do `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: @Sergio adicionei a imagem que peguei no debug do chrome na minha pergunta

Comment: boa idéia @AndersonCarlosWoss, vou olhar aqui.

Comment: @Sergio era isso mesmo, enviei direto o objeto sem o JSON,Stringify e passou blz. obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podem ocorrer aqui duas coisas:

- **Falta indicar o tipo de conteúdo**

Adicione a propriedade `contentType` com o valor `"application/json"` no objeto da função ajax. Isso faz com que o servidor entenda que você está mandando um Json e não um formulário HTML. I.e.:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json", // <------
  url: "http://localhost/api/pessoas",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  data: json_envio,
  success: function (result) {
      alert('tudo certo');
  },
  error: function (exception) { alert('Exeption:' + JSON.stringify(exception)); }
```

- **Aplicação de `JSON.stringify` a JSON válido**

Seu objeto já estava formatado como um JSON válido. Quando você aplica `JSON.stringify` de novo, você o "quebra" para o seu modelo - ele continua sendo um JSON válido, mas agora os nomes das propriedades incluem aspas duplas. A aplicação que recebe o modelo via ajax não consegue reconhecer essas propriedades como as propriedades que estava esperando. Se for algo como ASP.NET, você verá as propriedades como nulas ou com seu valores padrão no depurador.

Tente esses dois códigos no console do navegador e veja a diferença:

```
var x = {foo: 10};
JSON.stringify(x);
```

E compare com o resultado de:

```
var x = {"foo": "10"};
JSON.stringify(x);
```

Para não ter que se preocupar se os seus objetos já são JSON válido ou não, o ideal é você manter um padrão único no seu código. Ou declara tudo como JSON e não usa o `JSON.stringify`, ou declara tudo como objeto Javascript não-JSON e usa sempre o `JSON.stringify` antes de usar para o que quer que seja.

Comment: troquei o 'data: json_envio' por 'data: obj' como você sugeriu e funcionou blz, obrigado pela atenção!